# Can't search JBoss Maven (Nexus) repository anymore

Tags: maven, jboss, nexus

I have been trying for a couple of weeks now to access the search page for the JBoss Nexus repo at http://repository.jboss.org/nexus, with no luck.

I've noticed that they now require you to login with your Red Hat/Jboss account, but it seems that our users have no privileges to access the main search page, all we see is a "Loading Nexus UI" box.

Does anyone know what's going on? Access to the search page used to be public as well.

ps: access to the artifacts is still working. Only the nexus search that isn't.